# Kamailio Service fails to start when load tls.so or websocket.so module

Tags: websocket, kamailio, jssip

I am a beginner learning kamailio, i compile and install kamailio following instrution from the url below

https://kamailio.org/docs/tutorials/5.3.x/kamailio-install-guide-git/

however I realized  kamailio service won't start if attempt to load websocket.so or tls.so even though I have included these modules during compilation.

what could I be doing wrong please help.

I am trying to connect to kamailio using jssip

Comment: 99% it is missconfig. Where is programming question here? How we expected to debug this for you with info provided?

Comment: Thank you for heads up, your response lead to execute kamailio in debug mode, with this I was able to see the sources of all the errors  preventing kamailio from running.